# When did the events between issues 7 & 8 of Guardians of the Galaxy vol.3 occur?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

I'm reading Guardians of the Galaxy vol.3 and I think I got lost somewhere...

Can somebody explain me what happened in Vol.3 between the end of #7 and the "Infinity" stories of #8 and #9?

Thanos invaded Earth? The Avengers "have either fallen or are trapped behind enemy lines"?? When did *that* happen???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of that took place during the events of the [*Infinity*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinity_%28comic_book%29) crossover. The Avengers were in space to help the Galactic Alliance fight the Builders when Thanos took the opportunity to invade the Earth.  *Infinity* ties in with most of the Avengers-related titles, but the main storyline goes through *Infinity* #1-6, *Avengers* Vol. 5 #14-23, and *New Avengers* Vol. 3 #8-12.